# How to turn users input into a list in Python?

Tags: list, python-2.7, tkinter

Here is my code so far.

```
def pfunc():
    portList = []
    user_choice_port = userPort.get()
    portList.append(user_choice_port)
```

the `userPort` is basically a text variable for what the user will enter into an entry box (which will be ports). The user will enter the port numbers like this:

```
23, 80, 44, etc.
```

How do I take those numbers and put them into a list. Cause whenever I do it puts them in as a string that looks like this:

```
['23, 80, 44']
```

When I want it to look like this:

```
[23,80,44]
```

I cannot figure this out so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
user_choice_port = "23, 80, 44"
print map(int, user_choice_port.split(","))
print [int(n) for n in user_choice_port.split(",")]
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! But how can I .append() those results to a list? Like if I had a list called portList = []. How could I take an input and then just .append() them straight into it?